# In WoW which spec wears str+int gears? What about agi+int?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Sometimes the mob drops str+int or agi+int gears. I put them on the AH for a random price. Surprisingly they sell. My question is which class/specs need these stat combinations? I read the stat priority guides but couldn't find any.

Comment: If someone just sold you str+int gear, then you've been had :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there are any specs who would prefer those. There are several reasons that I can think of that people might buy them though.

Firstly if you put it on AH at lower than vendor price then somebody might have bought it just to sell to the vendor.

Secondly an enchanter may have bought it to disenchant either for leveling or because the materials gained by the DE are more valuable than the original item.

Lastly it is possible (though unlikely) that even with one useless stat the item is the best for that level on the AH at that time. This is very unlikely but it is at least plausible.

There may also be other reasons but this at least shows that it isn't pure insanity necessarily. :)

Edit to add:

Ravekner has pointed out in comments that it might be purely for the design of the item - they want it for transmogrification.

Comment: Never underestimate the stupidity of the leveling Ret Paladin in search of a larger Mana pool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As a new WoW player this is very informative to me:)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz from 5.0.4, "Intellect no longer increases mana pools" "The size of mana pools are fixed for each character level."  But yes, stupid ret pals...

Comment: @DavidB I did say "Don't underestimate the stupidity..."

Comment: Regardless of stats, some items just have a cooler design, so that could also be a reason why someone purchased them off the AH, transmogging kind of revitalized the Old World, Outlands and Northrend economy for farmers and players that enjoy doing older content. (Rarer designs can actually go for a pretty gold)

Comment: @Ravekner: Good point. I've only just come back to WoW after a long time so Transmog is still something I've only peripherally seen... I've edited my answer to include mention of that.

Comment: It can also be used for role-playing (RP).

Answer (score 3):

It's basically leftover from a time when the specs were different. For example when hunters had mana pools (and mana scaled with int) they would go for agi gear but also needed int/spirit to support their mana.

People buy this stuff because either A) its better than anything else on the auction house at the time for that level, or B) because it has transmogrification value.

You will stop finding gear like this at higher levels (after 60 I believe).